# What uses do we have for the epsilon-delta definition of a limit?

Tags: calculus

If we know a function's definition for all other points besides c, but we know that f is continuous at c, we can solve for the limit as x-> c by substituting c into f(x). As they say, *everybody knows that.* So why would we care about the epsilon-delta definition of the limit?

I suppose it'd be useful if we were unable to compute the limit but were able to obtain a graph and/or a table of values.

Comment: What if $f(c)$ is not defined?

Comment: The epsilon-delta definition of a limit is rigorous: one can find if it is true or not and one can use it to prove exact statements. Not all analysis is about explicit functions with nice formulas.

Comment: Even if $f(c)$ is defined, it might not be what you expect if $f$ is not continuous at $c$...

Comment: Even $f(x)$ is given explicitly, it doesn't mean that $f$ is continuous at $x=c$.

Comment: Limits (or continuous functions, or etc.) do not work that way.

Comment: One definition of continuity at $c$ I like: $f(\mu(c))\subseteq\mu(f(c))$. (The definition of $\mu$ is complicated, but you can think of $\mu(x)$ as meaning "the set of all things that are close to $x$." That's kind of vague, and it doesn't really help you with proofs, I guess, but an actual definition of $\mu$ would take too long.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a common example of a function in intro to analysis classes:  Define a function piecewise as $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is a rational number, and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.  Question:  Where is $f$ continuous?

With epsilon and deltas it's a simple matter to show that it's continuous at $0$ and discontinuous everywhere else.  Without the formal math, there's no way to approach a problem like this.

---

Added proof:
Continuity at 0:  Let $\epsilon >0$.  Our goal is to prove that the limit exists and is equal to $f(0)=0$.   So, we want a $\delta$ so that as long as $|x-0|<\delta, |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$.  in other words, we want as long as $|x|<\delta,|f(x)|<\epsilon$.  Well, either $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=0$,  in either case, $|f(x)|\le |x|$.  So,  if we just take $\delta =\epsilon$, we are done.

Discontinuity elsewhere:  If $x$ is irrational, there's a rational as close to it as you want, and since $f(x)=0$, but f on that rational is itself, we can never get all the values of $f$ to be sufficiently close.   Similarly, if $x$ is rational, there's an irrational closeby.   I'll skip the absolute formality here.

Comment: Added a proof.  It works for either case

Answer (score 2):

Your initial assumption is wrong -- you *cannot* find the limit by computing $f(c)$ *unless you already know the function is continuous*.

Functions defined by a particular arithmetic expressions will generally be continuous in their domain (and so finding their limits at such a point is a fairly trivial and uninteresting task), but those are not, by far, all the functions we're interested in.